# Multisite vs Role Scoper

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have a website with several sections. Each section will have their own user to administer content on. These wouldn't be large sections, maybe a few pages to a dozen at most.

My question is whether it would be worth the initial work setting up a Multisite or somehow using role scoper so that a user can only add child pages to a particular parent page

If role scoper is the way to go, what's the best way to go down this avenue?

Thanks

Comment: This is an open ended question and asks about the _opinion_ about a specific set of plugins (3rd party software is out of scope). Please read [ask], file an [edit] and bring that question in line so we don't have to close it.

Comment: Unfortunately your question doesn't fit this site's scope. Your question is too broad and most of all opinion based. Each site is unique and so are each situation and specific needs for a site. You are the only one that can decide what will be best for you based on your own knowledge and needs

Comment: Ok, I'll take this to the role scoper forum on WP